# How to prevent column sorting in XtraTreeList?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, devexpress

I am using devexpress and have a treelist with multiple columns.

Data gets rendered with a sorting of "ascending" by default per customer requirements.

**Problem**:

I have a button that should disable the sorting of columns. I have these two properties to work with: "`OptionsColumn.AllowSort`" and `SortOrder` . The problem is that even though I set the `OptionsColumn.AllowSort = false` a sort is still triggered when changing column values since I have a `SortOrder` of `Ascending`.

I found that If i change the `OptionsColumn.AllowSort = false` and `SortOrder` to `None` this gives me the desired behavior **BUT** when I change the sortOrder to None this triggers a sorting which confuses the customer.

**What I want:**

Simply put I need to "Freeze" the sorting which means when the user clicks on "DisableSorting" the list wont sort like when changing the sortOrder to "none" It will simply remain as it is and when changing the value the sort should not trigger.

code

*DisableButton*:

```
    private void DisableSorting_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in xtlItemList.Columns)
        {
            c.OptionsColumn.AllowSort = false; // disable sorting on all columns
        }

        EnableSorting= false; // global variable indicating that the sorting shoult be disabled

    }
```

treeList startSorting event:

```
        private void xtlItemList_StartSorting(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                var tree = (MatrixXTreeList)sender;
                DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn col = tree.GetSortColumn(0);

                if (EnableSorting == true) // if sorting enabled
                {

                    var treeTest = (MatrixXTreeList)sender;

                    DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListColumn col2 = treeTest.GetSortColumn(0);


                    if (col != null)
                        SetSortColumnID((MatrixXTreeList)sender, afterUpdate);
                    else
                    {
                        col.SortOrder = SortOrder.None;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    col.SortOrder = SortOrder.None; // if sorting diabled, 
//problem still triggers a sort since the SortOrder is changed from Ascending to None
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

How do I accomplish desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OptionsColumn.AllowSort](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Columns.TreeListOptionsColumn.AllowSort.property) help article describes that this property enables/disables only end-user capabilities. That is why it is expected that TreeList's nodes are still sorted on changing cell values. 
If you need to disable the sorting capabilities but show nodes in the current order, I suggest that you create a new data source based on the existing one keeping the current order of nodes. Then, assign this new data source to your TreeList and set the SortOrder property to None. When you turn on the sorting capabilities, assign the original data source to the control.

Comment: Interesting Idea, I will give it a go

Comment: Accepting this answer, please review my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Svetlana I managed to solve this. The solution is as follows:

First of I was looking for keeping the column values as is so I achived this by doing the following:

```
       public List<string> myValues= new List<string>();

        int count = xtlItemList.Nodes.Count; // number of nodes in three

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var columnID1 = xtlItemList.Columns[2]; // get the column with index of 2
            var cellValue = xtlItemList.Nodes[i][columnID1]; // get value

            myStrings.Add(cellValue.ToString()); // save value
        }

        // change sort order

        xtlItemList.BeginSort();
        xtlItemList.Columns[2].SortOrder = SortOrder.None;
        xtlItemList.EndSort();

        // return the values
        for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.Count; i++)
        {
            var columnID1 = xtlItemList.Columns[2];
            xtlItemList.Nodes[i].SetValue(columnID1, myStrings[i]);
        }
```

**HOWEVER**

The above would be wrong since I would be giving wrong values to each row. Since the sorting was changed the rows were rearranged so the values do not belong to the corresponding sorted row.

I solved this by saving the nodes in a list and then setting the position of the nodes after the sorting like so:

```
        int count = xtlItemList.Nodes.Count;

        List<TreeListNode> nodes = new List<TreeListNode>();
        nodes.AddRange(xtlItemList.Nodes); // save the nodes with their position

        xtlItemList.BeginSort();
        xtlItemList.Columns[2].SortOrder = SortOrder.None;
        xtlItemList.EndSort();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            xtlItemList.SetNodeIndex(nodes[i], i); // set nodes to the original position
        }
```